# How to grant the screen will be off?

Tags: screen-timeout

I have set 2min timeout.
The screen goes off after 2min.

The charger is not plugged (batt was at 100%, and after I sleep it would normally be at 95%).

Something happens that turns the screen on, and it will remain on forever (until I wakeup and find out it spent 35% of the battery...)

The only new notification was a provider unblockeable promo message, but that never caused that problem.

It has been happening for a few days now.

I need to enforce the screen go off, other than using the system option that is clearly not working.

Comment: related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197350/how-to-block-an-un-managed-popup

Answer (score 1):

It maybe that text notifications are waking up the screen at night. In that case you may need to completely disable notifications at night.

Some resolutions include:

1. Turn off message notification completely

You can stop the screen from turning on when you receive a message by disabling the message notification completely but you lose all the notifications, including audio **and LED flashing alerts**.

Depending on your device, navigate to  Menu  > Settings > Notifications and turn off.

2. Turn on Do not disturb feature (Android 6+ )

Do not disturb is a feature that lets you silent all notifications for a specific time period. You can choose to allow messages and calls from select contacts to still alert you when Do not disturb is enabled.

Open the Settings >> Sounds >> Do Not Disturb setting. On the Do not disturb settings screen, tap **Block visual disturbances**.

You additionally need to turn on the **Block when screen** is off option.

3. Using third party apps

Some users claim that apps such as [I'm sleeping](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zapek.android.sleeping&hl=en) have the ability to prevent screen wake-ups at night. This app will automatically set your phone to silent mode during the night and **optionally disables the LED during the 
night**

credits

- [Stop Notifications Waking Your Screen When Do Not Disturb Is Enabled In Android 7](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/stop-notifications-waking-your-screen-when-do-not-disturb-is-enabled-in-android-7/)

Comment: Did you manage  to solve this "screen off" problem?

Comment: mmm... do not disturb... I could use that for 24h!!! and only allow trusted ppl to annoy me xD. Have to try it now thx!

Comment: Some options are not available. But doNotDisturb will work 90% of the time! I will try to uninstall the stk package (sim toolkit) w/o root, tip from linked question, thx!