# how to block an OS app popup?

Tags: battery, ads, popup

Something on my smartphone sends a message once a day, sometimes I see a tiny fast dark background popup on the bottom saying it is doing so.

Such application seems related to the SIM card, as the popup I receive is from my cell phone provider/carrier/operator.

One second later I receive this:

[image: screenshot]

The app name is "Serviços TIM".
That app package name is "com.android.stk" (I found that using Brevent).
It is an OS App.
It has the exactly same version of "SIM ToolKit" (I guess .stk means that), but at apps list it is in an independent entry with it's own options.

The real huge problem is that, **when that popup shows and the screen is locked and remains like that for 8h+, the screen WILL NOT TURN OFF and will spend my battery from 100% to 40% or less** and I may depend on having the battery at that time! :(. I usually let it out of the charger, and without that popup it would only spend about 5-10% of the battery.

My smartphone J7 is not rooted, I wonder if that would be the only option?

---

**update**:

[image]

This other app I think is the culprit from sending the message. It already had SMS disabled but not the phone permission! (I have other app to let me read/send SMS btw)
[image]

also the SIM toolkit, I force stop it (and disabled all notifications now 2019):
[image]

---

**Final result is:** none of these actions above worked, the popup still happens :(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132832/discussion-on-question-by-aquarius-power-how-to-block-an-os-app-popup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the stk and stk2 package name and path, then back them up with pull :

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep stk

adb shell pm path com.android.stk
adb pull /system/app/Stk/Stk.apk

adb shell pm path com.android.stk2
adb pull /system/app/Stk2/Stk2.apk
```

Next we uninstall both :

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.stk
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.stk2
```

---

Old answer (in case you fear trying the uninstall steps above):

I managed to minimize the problem by using the "do not disturb" feature.
By "minimize" I mean that if I am using the phone the popup will still show up, otherwise it wont mess it's battery (neither show up).
I can allow all exceptions least "reminders" apparently.
Obs.: "do not disturb" is not 100%, I think about 10% of the times it will still allow that abusive popup to keep the screen ON for many hours!

The simToolkit app package "com.android.stk" (which I found out using Brevent), is called "Serviços TIM" and seems to be a mirroed/dup (???) package from the default simToolkit.

My next step (as soon that popup annoys me enough) is to try to uninstall that package by using this tip by @Izzy, thx!
[How to remove the SIM Toolkit from my phone? (Without root or flashing any ROM)](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206577/31723)

[adb uninstall failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534935/adb-uninstall-failed)
[Uninstall via adb without root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141473/uninstall-via-adb-without-root)
[How to disable Google Apps in Mi Phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194539/how-to-disable-google-apps-in-mi-phones/194693#194693)

Answer (score -2):

It seem to me like a flash message. These messages contain only two options- **Cancel** and **OK**. If you press **OK**, the plan mentioned in the message will get activated and it will cost you some money. This can be very irritating.

You can deactivate Flash messages but the process is different for different service providers

you can find the ways to stop flash messages in other operators [here](https://www.techtricksworld.com/how-to-stop-flash-messages/) and have an idea about your own service provider.

Comment: Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: There is no app "SIM Toolkit" here that I can run (it is on the configuration that shows the list of apps but not accessible/runnable as a normal app, I dont understand why they do that...), but there was the "ServiÇos ..." one! but it hadnt equivalent option...

Comment: This is definitely flash SMS that you are receiving because it contains information about some calling plans. Is there any other SIM/operator related application on your device?

Comment: does flash SMS comes thru CellBroadcasts? if so, I got a tip about SMS app where I can disable it, still testing what happens tho. I also deactivated all I could from SIM Toolkit about notifications in popups. I will add some info to the OP btw :)